# I have generated core-image-minimal on my linux and have installed qemu in windows, how do i run that in windows qemu?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, qemu

I have generated core-image-minimal on linux, i want to run that on windows qemu.[core-image-minimal files], what is the command to run the image?(in linux i used the command "runqemu core-image-minimal")

Comment: `Runqemu` is a yocto script that can use environment variables. To get real qemu command line, on your linux machine run  `runqemu core-image-minimal`, than run `ps -eo args` and find qemu command line in the output.

Comment: Right now i do not have linux machine, my intention is to run that core-image-minimal files in windows where i have installed qemu, i have copied the files that were built for core-image-minimal to windows

Comment: You have to do the test on linux machine to find out the exact qemu command line. Without it you can only guess it.